# Iterate through list in async for loop

Tags: python, list, docker, for-loop, asynchronous

I'm having some trouble iterating through a list using an async for method. I'm essentially trying to use async to connect to all running docker containers and have each one's stats sent via a websocket. The following is what I have so far:

```
@router.websocket("/stats")
async def dashboard(websocket: WebSocket):
    # auth_success = await websocket_auth(websocket=websocket)
    # if auth_success:
    await websocket.accept()
    tasks = []
    async with aiodocker.Docker() as docker: 
        containers = await docker.containers.list()
        for app in containers:
            _name = app._container['Names'][0][1:]
            container: DockerContainer = await docker.containers.get(_name)
            stats = container.stats(stream=True)
            tasks.append(process_container(_name, stats))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def process_container(name, stats):
    cpu_total = 0.0
    cpu_system = 0.0
    cpu_percent = 0.0
    async for line in stats:
        mem_current = line["memory_stats"]["usage"]
        mem_total = line["memory_stats"]["limit"]

        try:
            cpu_percent, cpu_system, cpu_total = await calculate_cpu_percent2(line, cpu_total, cpu_system)
        except KeyError as e:
            print("error while getting new CPU stats: %r, falling back")
            cpu_percent = await calculate_cpu_percent(line)

        full_stats = {
            "name": _name,
            "time": line['read'],
            "cpu_percent": cpu_percent,
            "mem_current": mem_current,
            "mem_total": line["memory_stats"]["limit"],
            "mem_percent": (mem_current / mem_total) * 100.0,
        }
        await websocket.send_text(json.dumps(full_stats))
```

This returns `raise RuntimeError('Session is closed')`

Here is the full traceback:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/dev/Yacht-work/Yacht/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/websockets/websockets_impl.py", line 154, in run_asgi
    result = await self.app(self.scope, self.asgi_receive, self.asgi_send)
  File "/home/user/dev/Yacht-work/Yacht/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/user/dev/Yacht-work/Yacht/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 180, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/user/dev/Yacht-work/Yacht/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/user/dev/Yacht-work/Yacht/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 146, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/user/dev/Yacht-work/Yacht/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 58, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/user/dev/Yacht-work/Yacht/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/user/dev/Yacht-work/Yacht/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 283, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/user/dev/Yacht-work/Yacht/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 57, in app
    await func(session)
  File "/home/user/dev/Yacht-work/Yacht/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 242, in app
    await dependant.call(**values)
  File "./backend/api/routers/apps.py", line 133, in dashboard
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "./backend/api/routers/apps.py", line 139, in process_container
    async for line in stats:
  File "/home/user/dev/Yacht-work/Yacht/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiodocker/containers.py", line 299, in _stats_stream
    async with cm as response:
  File "/home/user/dev/Yacht-work/Yacht/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiodocker/utils.py", line 309, in __aenter__
    resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/user/dev/Yacht-work/Yacht/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiodocker/docker.py", line 241, in _do_query
    response = await self.session.request(
  File "/home/user/dev/Yacht-work/Yacht/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 357, in _request
    raise RuntimeError('Session is closed')
RuntimeError: Session is closed
```